# Create relationship between two query delphi

Tags: delphi, datasource, fastreport, tclientdataset

I have two table Country and City (country_id is PK in Country table and country_id is FK in City table).

Which component use to create relation between two query for fast report.

[image: our]

Which structure should be:

1. Query  2. Client Data set .... 3. ?  4.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually called a Master-Detail relationship between the datasets involved.

In Delphi, you set one up by connecting the Detail dataset to a TDataSource whose dataset is the connected to the Master dataset.  You can do this on the server side (i.e between the two queries, using the `DataSource` property of the Detail or between two clientdatasets using the `MasterSource` property of the.Detail.  When doing it on the server side, you write the SQL for the query as a parameterised query, with the parameter being one whose value matches the Master's PK as in

```
  Select * from mydetailtable where masterid = :masterid
```

Once a Master-Detail relationship has been set up between two datasets, it should work with virtually any report generator, FastReports included.

See e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Setting_Up_Master-Detail_Linked_Relationships which talks about this in terms of DBExpress components, but the principle is applicable to other Delphi dataset components.